# Why my code is giving error after i submit code

Tags: c, runtime-error

In CodeChef website [problem SQUIDRULE](https://www.codechef.com/INFI21C/problems/SQUIDRULE) it is giving me a runtime error after submitting but when I run the program it is giving me right answer and also run sucessfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int T, s, a[1000], b[100];
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T--) {
        scanf("%d", &s);

        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
            int sum = 0, c;

            for (int j = 1; j <= s; j++) {
                sum = sum + a[j];
            }

            c = sum - a[i];
            b[i] = c;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <=s; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <=s; j++) {
                if (b[i] > b[j]) {
                    int c;
                    c = b[i];
                    b[i] = a[j];
                    b[j] = c;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",b[s]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What error are you getting?

Comment: Because your code takes too long to run. You need to redesign the algorithm to be more efficient.

Comment: In general, code challenges like this require you to come up with clever solutions. The obvious iterative solution will fail for large inputs.

Comment: Array-indexes in C are *zero* based. Don't use one-based indexing. Such things would be taught and learned if you used a *proper* teaching or learning resource, like good books and taking classes. So-called "competition" and "online judge" sites are *not* teaching or learning resources.

Comment: What is your input?  On certain inputs, `T` remains uninitialized before `while(T--)`, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you have UB (undefined behavior)? What is the [practical] max array size? That is, what is the maximum value for `s`? You do: `a[1000]` but only `b[100]`. They are _both_ indexed by the same index variables, so I presume `b` should be `b[1000]`. Otherwise, you can index beyond the end of `b`

Comment: In your second set of nested `for` loops, which take O(n^2) time, you are sorting [using _slow_ bubble sort instead of `qsort`?]. At the end, you only want to print `b[s]`. AFAICT, you do _not_ need to sort at all. You're just looking for the min/max value of the array, so you can calculate that in O(n) time.

Comment: Further, `sum` is _invariant_ across all iterations of `i`. So, you can move the `j` loop above the second `i` and only calculate it _once_. Once again, you can reduce running time from O(n^2) to O(n)

Comment: There can be 10^5 players so the array (if you *need* an array) must be `int a[100000]` not `int a[1000]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane 2≤N≤10^5 so 100001?

Comment: @CraigEstey not neccessary usually, but in this code OP is indexing from `1` so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comments ...

In your second set of nested for loops, which take O(n^2) time, you are sorting [using slow bubble sort instead of qsort?]. At the end, you only want to print b[s].

AFAICT, you do *not* need to sort at all. You're just looking for the max value of the array, so you can calculate that in O(n) time.

Further, `sum` is invariant across all iterations of `i`. So, you can move the j loop above the second i and only calculate it once. Once again, you can reduce running time from O(n^2) to O(n)

---

As WeatherVane pointed out, you need [at least] 10,000 entries in `a`.

Additionally, you can eliminate the separate `for` loop for calculating the `sum` by doing this in the `scanf` loop.

Here is a refactored version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AMAX    (100000 + 10)
int s, a[AMAX];
int sum;

int
fast(void)
{

    int mx = sum - a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {
        int c = sum - a[i];
        if (c > mx)
            mx = c;
    }

    return mx;
}

int
main(void)
{

    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T--) {
        scanf("%d", &s);

        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            sum += a[i];
        }

        int v2 = fast();
        printf("%d\n",v2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ I submitted this as a practice on the site [because submission time was already up] and it ran successfully in 0.05 seconds (so, 20x faster than needed).